# OpenManage Essentials is not getting health status

Tags: dell-openmanage

I'm installing Dell OpenManage Essentials on my new computer.  Everything worked correctly on my old computer -- 16 servers, inventoried, with health status, server tags, model numbers, etc.

On my new computer, I can see the 16 servers, but they are all listed as "Unclassified" and unknown health status.

My old computer was Windows 7 and my new computer is Windows 10.  Other than that, I can't find any major differences between the two computers.  I have the same IP address as before with the same SSH tunnels; I can connect to port 443 on all of the servers; Windows Firewall appears to be set up the same (although I haven't checked it line by line).  I don't think it's a network problem because I'm having the issue across multiple servers on multiple networks.  My co-worker can still see all of the servers and all of their statuses.

If anybody can give me a suggestion as to how I can troubleshoot further, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using SNMP, WMI, etc.? Are you able to run the troubleshooting tool to connect to the server(s) with WMI or SNMP? It's not a Windows firewall issue or local client firewall application blocking management traffic?

Comment: @DT I can't even install OME anymore, so I may not be able to answer your questions.  *sigh*